# Jenkins v2.7.3 - hudson.security.ACL.as(Lorg/acegisecurity/Authentication;)Lhudson/security/ACLContext

Tags: jenkins

I am new to `jenkins` and installed `2.7.3` in my system it work fine. But after restart the computer then getting below error

```
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.security.ACL.as(Lorg/acegisecurity/Authentication;)Lhudson/security/ACLContext;
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:241)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.security.ACL.as(Lorg/acegisecurity/Authentication;)Lhudson/security/ACLContext;
    at jenkins.branch.WorkspaceLocatorImpl$Collector.onOnline(WorkspaceLocatorImpl.java:521)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:914)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:227)
```

I have tried to add plugin folder and restarted the computer. No luck

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed. Please uninstall tomcat9 and install it again. Refer below link
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-18-04/ - applicable for linux 16.04 too